# Why did I failed to convert IntPtr to byte[]?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll

I'm working on a project with making DLL to do model's inference from C#.

During the inference process, we do the pre-processing, inference, and post-processing to complete the work.
At the beginning, I write all these process in one DLL, and it works fine.
But for the concept of "modularity", my boss ask me to split these process into three different DLLs.

So, the ideal dataflow should be like this:

```
                        C#          ||        DLL    (return cv::Mat*)
pre-processing  ||  image->byte[] -----> Mat (...) -> new Mat(result)
                                                            ↓
============================================================↓==============
                        Intptr   <---------------------------
==========================↓================================================
inference       ||      byte[]    -----> Mat (...) -> new Mat(result)
                                                            ↓
============================================================↓==============
                        Intptr   <---------------------------
==========================↓===============================================
post-processing ||      byte[]    -----> Mat (...) -> new Mat(result)
```

But during the process of passing cv::Mat* to C# and pass the byte[] converted from Intptr,
the input data(cv::Mat) **is not the same** as it showed from the original cv2.Mat(Intptr). And here's the code I write for doing these(it's simplified...):

```
//C++(DLL)
//pre-processing DLL ---------------------------------------------------
//dll_pre.h
extern "C" LIB_API cv::Mat* img_padding(unsigned char* img_pointer, int img_H, int img_W, int* len);

//dll_pre.cpp
LIB_API cv::Mat* img_padding(unsigned char* img_pointer, int img_H, int img_W)
{
    cv::Mat input_pic = cv::Mat(img_H, img_W, CV_8UC(pic_ch), img_pointer);

    //do something...

    *len = input_pic.total() * input_pic.elemSize();

    return new cv::Mat(input_pic);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

//inference DLL --------------------------------------------------------
//dll_inf.h
extern "C" LIB_API void dll_inference(unsigned char* img_pointer, int img_H, int img_W);

//dll_inf.cpp'
LIB_API void dll_inference(unsigned char* img_pointer, int img_H, int img_W)
{
    cv::Mat input_pic = cv::Mat(img_H, img_W, CV_8UC(pic_ch), img_pointer);

    cv::imwrite("dll_pic.png", input_pic)

    //do something...
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
//C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing; //Bitmap
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO; //Memory Stream
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //Marshal
using System.Diagnostics;//Timer
using OpenCvSharp;


namespace Test_DLL_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"dll_pre.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr img_padding(byte[] img, int img_H, int img_W, out int rt_len);
        [DllImport(@"dll_inf.dll")]
        private static extern void dll_inference(byte[] img, int img_H, int img_W);

        public static byte[] GetRGBValues(Bitmap bmp, out int bmp_w)
        {
            // Lock the bitmap's bits. 
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
             bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

            // Get the address of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

            Console.WriteLine($"bytes->{bytes}");
            // Copy the RGB values into the array.
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes); bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            bmp_w = bmpData.Stride;
            return rgbValues;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap("test_pic.bmp");
            int img_W = 0;
            int rt_len = 0;
            byte[] dst = GetRGBValues(image, out img_W);
            IntPtr pre_res = img_padding(dst, image.Height, img_W, out rt_len);
            //Mat pad_res = new Mat(pre_res); //This is the way I get return picture from DLL in C#
            ////pad_res is different from dll_pic.png I saved from dll_inf
            byte[] btarr = new byte[rt_len];
            Marshal.Copy(pre_res, btarr, 0, rt_len);
            dll_inference(btarr, image.Height, img_W);
        }
    }
}
```

To sum up, so far I've done the conversion from IntPtr to byte[] successfully:

> dataflow: IntPtr >> Mat >> Bitmap >> byte[]

But it'll take too much time for the conversion(in my opinion...), so I want to make it more simple

I also tried another way of conversion but it still failed:

> dataflow: IntPtr >> Mat >> byte[]

with this code

```
//C#
byte[] btarr = new byte[rt_len];
Mat X = new Mat(pre_res);
X.GetArray(image.Height, img_W, btarr);
dll_inference(btarr, image.Height, img_W);
//(But the result is also different from the way it should be...)
```

I don't know where did I do wrong...
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: When you say not the same how much different are the bytes?  Is it a few bytes that are different or most of the file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply! I think it's different for most of the file(?) Here's the [pictures](https://imgur.com/a/bGzBuA6) produced from the way IntPtr-> byte[] and pass to another dll  (original(dll_pre)/converted(dll_inf) one)

Comment: In this case a picture is not worth a 1000 words.  You could have one byte different and get that results.  It does tell me the image is valid, otherwise, you would of gotten an error indicating the file was corrupted.  My suspicion this has nothing to do with the passing of the data from c# to c++ and back to c#.  The c++ code isn't working with all types of images.  Test the c++ by itself with same image and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, I've tested passing the same pic between two different DLL with C#(the input type and the way it parse byte[] to image are the same in two DLL). But if it get the byte[] converted from Intptr, the image changed as I showed at the above comment(that's why I suspect it's the problem with the conversion of Intptr --> byte[]). I'll try other ways to deal with this problem, thanks for your reply!

Comment: The bytes in c++ are in unmanaged memory and are copied to managed memory using Marshal.Copy().  If there was anything wrong with the location or size you would of gotten and exception with the copy.  So if there was anything wrong it would be with the img_padding.  So my suspicions are the height and width you are using in c# are not the same as in c++.

Comment: Hi, I've checked the image size problem you mentioned above. In my case, my image height and width are the same, and I also checked the length of byte[] it produced, it's the same as its H x W. They're all the same, but the result is still incorrect...Q_Q I'll keep trying, and record the process here if there's any update. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you swapping height and width?  Where is origin of picture?  Upper left or Lower left?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your patient...QAQ. For the first question, I think the answer is NO(?). I mean, the image in my case, its weight equal to its height, it's a square, so it doesn't matter if I swap the H and W(?), sorry for my bad expression...

Comment: As for the latter, I've searched online, but I don't know how to check this part's information...
(I've tried printed out the content of byte[] using ```Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(btarr)) Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(btarr)) Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(btarr))```, but the result showed like garbled or some combination of E0-E0-E0-E0-80-E0-A0..., I have no idea how to check the question you asked Orz)

Comment: Try  : btarr.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("X2"));

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply and patient again. Sorry for asking a stupid question... I've tried to text the code you showed above like this ```Console.WriteLine(btarr.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("X2")));``` in my C# program, but it showed ```System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Byte,System.String]``` in my console, where did I do wrong? QQ

Comment: The output was char[].  So try : Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",btarr.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("X2"))));  So fix is using join with a string empty.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your patient again...
I printed out the content of byte array with your code(it showed something like 0x00),
and I use python to convert all the output to int, and it's totally different from the pic it should be...
(although they're all integer with value, but still very different like [this](https://ppt.cc/fbDzex)) I also found out that I can print out the integer value of byte[] in C# directly using this code `for (int i = 0; i < btarr.Length; i++) {Console.Write(btarr[i]);Console.Write(", ");} ` (Or doesn't these value represent the content of my converted byte[]?)

Comment: I found out the proper way of converting Mat to byte[], it shoud be like
`X.GetArray(0, 0, btarr);
(The first and second parameter is not its height and width...)
`
And I printed out the result with the code I mentioned above, it's the same with the original one.
So, so far, the conversion with dataflow `IntPtr >> Mat >> byte[]` can work, but `IntPtr >> byte[]` can't.
Can it be opencv module use different way to arrange(?) its IntPtr that cause this result?

Comment: I always go back to Wiki when there is a question on a bit map file : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: I've tried to pass byte[] from C# to DLL, then back to C# without any process. I use the same syntax `Marshal.Copy(pre_res, btarr, 0, rt_len);` to convert IntPtr to byte[], and pass it to another DLL, the picture stay the same as it should be. So, I think I misuse the conversion between IntPtr get from cv::Mat* and byte[]. Without the opencv module, the code works fine.

Comment: That is what I said last week.  I thought the c++ code was the issue.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding...Q_Q, and I really appreciate your patient and advice!!

Comment: there are two reasons the MAT may fail 1) The size of Mat and byte are different so make sure you copying the correct sizes.  2) If there is a pointer in MAT to a different object.  Then you need to move the pointer object from unmanaged c++ memory to managed c# memory.